# Batch change pooling parameters in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

I am trying to write a script in order to change the pooling parameters of all services within an ArcGIS Server 10.5 folder. I am having difficulty looping through and editing the JSON. The script runs without error, but the service parameters are not changed.

```
# For Http calls
import httplib, urllib, json

# For system tools
import sys

# For reading passwords without echoing
import getpass


# Defines the entry point into the script
def main(argv=None):
    # Print some info
    print
    print "This tool is a sample script"
    print  
    
    # Ask for admin/publisher user name and password
    username = "xxx"
    password = "xxx"
    
    # Ask for server name
    serverName = "xxx"
    serverPort = 6080

    folder = 'Geobasisdaten'
    
    # Get a token
    token = getToken(username, password, serverName, serverPort)
    if token == "":
        print "Could not generate a token with the username and password provided."
        return
    
            
    folderURL = "/arcgis/admin/services/commandx/"
    
    # This request only needs the token and the response formatting parameter 
    params = urllib.urlencode({'token': token, 'f': 'json'})
    
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
    
    # Connect to URL and post parameters    
    httpConn = httplib.HTTPConnection(serverName, serverPort)
    httpConn.request("POST", folderURL, params, headers)
    
    # Read response
    response = httpConn.getresponse()
    if (response.status != 200):
        httpConn.close()
        print "Could not read folder information."
        return
    else:
        data = response.read()
        
        # Check that data returned is not an error object
        if not assertJsonSuccess(data):          
            print "Error when reading folder information. " + str(data)
        else:
            print "Processed folder information successfully. Now processing services..."

        # Deserialize response into Python object
        dataObj = json.loads(data)
        httpConn.close()

        # Loop through each service in the folder and stop or start it    
        for item in dataObj['services']:
            

                # Edit desired properties of the service
            dataObj["minInstancesPerNode"] = 0
            dataObj["maxInstancesPerNode"] = 2

                # Serialize back into JSON
            updatedSvcJson = json.dumps(dataObj)

                # Call the edit operation on the service. Pass in modified JSON.
            editSvcURL = folderURL + str(item["serviceName"])+ ".MapServer" + "/edit" 
            print editSvcURL
            params = urllib.urlencode({'token': token, 'f': 'json', 'service': updatedSvcJson})
            
            httpConn.request("POST", editSvcURL, params, headers)
                
                # Read service edit response
            editResponse = httpConn.getresponse()
            if (editResponse.status != 200):
                httpConn.close()
                print "Error while executing edit."
                return
            else:
                editData = editResponse.read()
                    
                    # Check that data returned is not an error object
                if not assertJsonSuccess(editData):
                    print "Error returned while editing service" + str(editData)        
                else:
                    print "Service edited successfully."

            httpConn.close()            
        
        return


# A function to generate a token given username, password and the adminURL.
def getToken(username, password, serverName, serverPort):
    # Token URL is typically http://server[:port]/arcgis/admin/generateToken
    tokenURL = "/arcgis/admin/generateToken"
    
    params = urllib.urlencode({'username': username, 'password': password, 'client': 'requestip', 'f': 'json'})
    
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Accept": "text/plain"}
    
    # Connect to URL and post parameters
    httpConn = httplib.HTTPConnection(serverName, serverPort)
    httpConn.request("POST", tokenURL, params, headers)
    
    # Read response
    response = httpConn.getresponse()
    if (response.status != 200):
        httpConn.close()
        print "Error while fetching tokens from admin URL. Please check the URL and try again."
        return
    else:
        data = response.read()
        httpConn.close()
        
        # Check that data returned is not an error object
        if not assertJsonSuccess(data):            
            return
        
        # Extract the token from it
        token = json.loads(data)        
        return token['token']            
        

# A function that checks that the input JSON object 
#  is not an error object.
def assertJsonSuccess(data):
    obj = json.loads(data)
    if 'status' in obj and obj['status'] == "error":
        print "Error: JSON object returns an error. " + str(obj)
        return False
    else:
        return True
    
        
# Script start
if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an attempt to multiplex this in the code -- No list of targets or request to list all services for iteration.  Port 6080 should be long dead; everything is done on 6443 now.

Comment: If you don't include your attempt, we can't show you how to fix it (and the question will be closed for not trying). Removing the 'raw_input' calls and adding iteration is all you need here. I found tons of examples when I had to look years ago, but I found enabling tracing in the browser consol to be the easiest way to structure the net requests.

Comment: Okay, so maybe some diagnostics in the code, printing what you've attempted to send?  It doesn't look like you set a legal value in `folder` (on which you should be iterating).